# call to a member function getIdFieldName on boolean - Magento1

Tags: magento-1.9

We are getting this error randomly in admin side of Magento1

May be in dashboard, order list, products grid etc..

It may clear once we cleared the redis cache or came back after taking a different menu.
[image]

This happening after a new server migration and occurs very randomly like daily once or twice.

We are using redis cache and file based session.

Any fix against for this ?

Comment: You have a custom model with an undefined resource. Make sure every custom model that uses a table has a resource properly defined.

Comment: Thanks for replying..i will check that
but why that error going after taking few menus ?
Also at the same time some other admins logged in and it will be working for them :)

Comment: If you can get the complete trace of the exception and paste it, it will provide more glues.

Comment: when tracing the error, its ending with a valid attribute which working fine.
If we refresh the error page about 5-6 times, the error may go and page will load fine. We are using a remote redis-server for caching.. doubt which makes this issue but not sure.

Comment: I was hoping that you would copy paste the error trace here. Otherwise, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Source model "eav/entity_attribute_source_table" not found for attribute "gender"". This is the error getting in reports..  but actually this attribute have proper values in option and option_values.  And the error disappers after refresh 5-6 times. Is it something because of redis ?

Comment: The source model error and `getIdFieldName()` are different things. Without the trace, it's hard to say what is going on.

Comment: Can you tell me a trace method ? My tracing ending with an existing attribute

Comment: Add these in your root/index.php: `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('error_prepend_string', '<pre>'); ini_set('error_append_string', '</pre>');`

Comment: Tried the same.. but no luck to get  more details. The error basically happending when using redis. There is no issues when i am using local file cache.  a:5:{i:0;s:81:"Source model "eav/entity_attribute_source_table" not found for attribute "gender"";i:1;s:2934:"#0 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "e...')
But this errir disappears after few refresh..

Comment: The error trace you posted seems fine, however, it looks like you truncated it. Can you paste the whole thing? The first 3 chars `a:5` means array of 5 elements, but I can see only 2 elements in the array.

Comment: here the complete contents https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQrIWpEQ

Comment: Magento cannot find the classes, check autoload directories `$paths` in `Mage.php` are intact in your installation. I'm not sure what version you have, but check that compiler is disabled.

Comment: thanks for the help. It seems the issue coming when redis enabled. So for now i have changed the cache to file system.